Error in IIS while publishing app locally, Entity Framework Core migrations do not work

As you see there is a command on "Entity Framework Migrations" which shows an error message:
dotnet ef dbcontext list --json 


More than one project was found in the current working directory. Use the --project

This is my full project from github: https://github.com/gabriegsti/MinhaApiCompleta
I tried searching in the web about this error, I've already checked many different answers in Stack Overflow, most of them are old, and none of them were solutions for similar cases.

There are 2 .csproj files under DevIO.API folder, please check it.

I didnt find, please show me the path.

Could you kindly check this picture ?

Hi Gabriel, does the findings in my comment useful? If it help, do you mind me summarize it as answer below? Tks~

You realy helped me, please make it an answer!

Thanks for your confirmation, have a nice day.

According to the error message, it means there are multiple projects were found during the migration/publish.
The we can check the publish files with extension name .csproj. Make sure one project has one .csproj file. Then we can build/piblish the project successful.
